# Required request body is missing when using interceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm doing this strict schema validation using an interceptor (so I can get the InputStream value from the HttpServletRequest class).

```
public class RequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

  @Override
  public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception exception)
      throws Exception {
    // Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
  public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView)
      throws Exception {
    // Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
  public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

    InputStream parameters = request.getInputStream();

    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS);
    mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

    switch (request.getContentType()) {
      case "V0":
        try {
          mapper.readValue(parameters, new TypeReference<JsonApi<CountryVo>>() {});
        }catch (final UnrecognizedPropertyException e) {

          throw new UnrecognizedRequestException();
        }
      case "V1":
      default:
        try {
          mapper.readValue(parameters,
              new TypeReference<JsonApi<CountryVoV1>>() {
              });
        } catch (final UnrecognizedPropertyException e) {

          throw new UnrecognizedRequestException();

        }
    }


    return true;
  }

}
```

What I'm doing in this is just checking the expect DTO, based on the content-type the user sent, and then if it's wrong, I expect it to throw the UnrecognizedPropertyException.

The problem with this is that later on it throws Required request body is missing - for the right payloads. When I stop using this interceptor, the problem goes away.

Comment: What you are doing wrong is that you are trying to read the request twice and that isn't possible.

Comment: But this is actually passing.

Comment: It isn't else it would be available in the controller. You are reading it in your interceptor that way it isn't available anymore in the controller.